# How to use iemoji on edge

Tags: html, emoji

I have this code :

```
<option> &#x1F1E9;&#x1F1EA; Deutsch</option>
or 
<option> &#127465;&#127466; Deutsch</option>
```

and I get this on Firefox :
[image]

but on Edge it looks like this :
[image]

What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, Windows comes without system Emoji font containing colourful flag ligatures <del>(and many more glyphs from Emoji land)</del>. Since Chrome and Edge rely on system fonts, we see those simple characters and not the ligature.

Firefox (still) embeds its own nice fallback Emoji font based on Twitters ("Twemoji Mozilla") to mitigate this. So the only way to get it working across browsers is to provide webfont.

There is nicely usable Mozilla's Twemoji font compiled for web usage by Maxime Euziere at https://xem.github.io/unicode13/emoji.html :

```css
/*
Licenses for TwemojiMozilla.ttf: https://github.com/mozilla/twemoji-colr/blob/master/LICENSE.md#license-for-the-visual-design
Derived from: https://twemoji.twitter.com/
Source: https://xem.github.io/unicode13/emoji.html 
*/
@font-face {
  font-family: "Twemoji from xem.github.io";
  src: url("https://xem.github.io/unicode13/Twemoji.ttf") format("truetype");
  unicode-range: U+00A9-E007F;
  /* @see https://github.com/mozilla/twemoji-colr/issues/56 */
}

:root {
  font-family: "Twemoji from xem.github.io", Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol, Segoe, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>&#x1F1E9;&#x1F1EA; Deutsch
```

Comment: not beautiful but acceptable  :))

Comment: "Sadly, Windows comes without system Emoji font containing colourful flag ligatures (**and many more glyphs from Emoji land**). "  
@myf: The only Unicode emoji _not_ supported in Windows are the flags. (Flag emoji were always a bad idea, but unfortunately one of the major vendors decided to support them, and others followed. I think they all regret it now.)

Comment: @PeterConstable Good point, I was probably under super outdated impression from 2016-ish or from reports from frozen corporate installations - I remember quite regularly stumbling upon "monochrome" or "tofu" 'emoji' in Chrome on Windows while Firefox displayed its Twemoji fork.  But I see it might have been just wrong font stack avoiding Segoe UI Emoji after all (?), 2019 update seems pretty concise (https://blog.emojipedia.org/diverse-emoji-families-come-to-windows/)
I agree that all this flag mechanics is, well, interesting at least, haven't put much thought into it.